# Plugin or standalone audio player to verbally announce next song

Tags: windows, media-player

I often just set my Windows Media Player to play shuffle [random] from my whole collection (which is actually a mix of my collection, my parents and my sister's so it has a very wide range). I'm often busy, doing dishes or something and I don't want to have to wash my hands and go to the computer to find out what that song is if I'm really enjoying a song.

So I want to have the player announce the song Title/Contributing Artist.

I'm fine with it being a plugin or standalone player. If it is standalone player/plugin to something other than Windows Media Player; my requirements are pretty much nothing - be able to read (recursively) through a folder for music files and play shuffle/random. I'm fine to have to do library management elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know of any already available, but it might be a fun project for someone to write a VLC plugin that goes out to a free Text-to-Speech web service before each song.

Comment: @BenMiller Yeah if nothing is available I'll be adding it to my list of things I may someday code - though I think I'd probably go for working offline.

Comment: (A geeky comment), it will be better to announce verbally the song that has just finished before start playing the next one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Metal Player](http://www.abyssalsoft.com/metal-player) has an option to verbally announce next song, or the song that has just finished. Default it's disabled, but you can enable this option from Settings > Intelligent Playback.

It has options to add files/folders and play them as you want: random, recursively or based on your musical preferences (it has some intelligent playback algorithms that learns your preferences with each song that you play).

Note: Metal Player uses Microsoft Speech. The best experience is obtained on Windows 8, which Microsoft has greatly improved speech synthesis. In older versions of Windows the voice is not as realistic.

Comment: This is almost perfect - the only problem is although I'm fine to do library *management* elsewhere I wish I could easily rather than by folder select files from my library to play. It isn't a big issue though so since it does meet all my stated requirements and there doesn't seem to be any other options forthcoming I'm accepting it. Thanks :D